# No glob expansion without -re option in Expect

Tags: tcl, expect

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn passwd [lindex $argv 0]
set password [lindex $argv 1]

expect -nocase "pass*" {
      send "$password\r"
}

expect -nocase "password" {
      send "$password\r"
}

expect eof
```

How can I prevent expect to expand the glob `*` in `pass*`? This is just an example. In my actual code, I want to keep the glob, but I don't want to at `-ex`, which stands for exact match, or `-re` option for regex.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a glob-style match, use the `-gl` option before it:

```
expect {
    -gl -nocase "pass*" {
        # Do something...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you wrote to prevent from globing of `*` use `-ex`. By default `-gl` is assumed. Or use `-re` and escape `*` as: `\\*`.