# Linux : Zip all the files with same suffix using expect script

Tags: linux, expect

**List of files in the folder :**

$ ll *txt

```
-rw-rw-rw- 1 psawant CVS_GROUP 32 Mar 25 13:34 File.txt
-rw-rw-rw- 1 psawant CVS_GROUP 51 Mar 25 13:34 File_Changes.txt
-rw-rw-rw- 1 psawant CVS_GROUP 29 Mar 25 13:35 file1.txt
-rw-rw-rw- 1 psawant CVS_GROUP 29 Mar 25 13:35 file2.txt
-rw-rw-rw- 1 psawant CVS_GROUP 29 Mar 25 13:35 file3.txt
```

**Expect script to tar the files with fixed name and all the other files with prefix "file" :**

$ cat tar.exp

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set timeout -1
match_max 100000

set PWD "12345"

set FILE1 "File.txt"
set FILE2 "File_Changes.txt"

spawn zip -e -j ZIP.zip $FILE1 $FILE2 file*
expect "Enter password:"
sleep 1
send -- "$PWD\r"
sleep 1
expect "Verify password:"
sleep 1
send -- "$PWD\r"
sleep 3
interact
```

**When I run it from script it considers file* as a file name but when I take the same spawn command and run it directly it works.**

```
$ tar.exp
spawn zip -e -j ZIP.zip File.txt File_Changes.txt file*
Enter password: 
Verify password: 
        zip warning: name not matched: file*
updating: File.txt (deflated 16%)
updating: File_Changes.txt (deflated 35%)

$ zip -e -j ZIP.zip File.txt File_Changes.txt file*
Enter password: 
Verify password: 
updating: File.txt (deflated 16%)
updating: File_Changes.txt (deflated 35%)
  adding: file1.txt (deflated 24%)
  adding: file2.txt (deflated 24%)
  adding: file3.txt (deflated 24%)
```

**How can make it work from the script.What change do I need to make in order it make this change ?**

Comment: What don't you use a while loop and iterate over the files ?

Comment: Because files are not necessarily with sequential number. It can be anything - file2567.txt or file31456.txt

Comment: Ohk. It seems globbing characters are not supported. Try using set +f in your script to enable globbing.

Comment: Heres a link for your reference for expect. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9630185/no-glob-expansion-without-re-option-in-expect

Comment: You might find that switching to `7z` will significantly reduce your scripting problems, and allow you to ditch `expect` entirely.

Comment: Thanks for your help Ajit. Issue is resolved with your solution and small other tweak.

Answer (score 1):

If you use your shell to enter the command the shell itself expands `file*` to a list of all files which matches this pattern.

Tcl which runs expect have no idea if your given text is a pattern to expand or not. If you want tcl to expand your pattern use the tcl `glob` command.

```
set files [ glob file*]
puts $files
```

Comment: Probably want to add `-nocomplain` option. Documentation: http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/glob.htm

Comment: @Prasad, using `glob` is the correct way to go. An alternative is to force the shell to expand the wildcard: `spawn sh -c {zip -e -j ZIP.zip File.txt File_Changes.txt file*}'`